# How to configure a button to run a method in vba

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, vba, button, dynamics-gp

I have a custom application I am developing in vba. I have written all the code and the only thing I am confused about is how to configure a button to actually "start" or "run" the program. On the form on the user side, the user will type in an item number, then a button will be pushed that brings up a bunch of fields and textboxes on a new small form for the user to enter, The window displays the default values and will update/save new or updated fields and insert it into the database.

The button is designed in microsoft-gp but I have to manually code it to run the program.

Right now, when I click the button, the window pops up, but no information is displayed in the textboxes nor are the combobox values being displayed.

Here is the beginning of my program.

```
 Private rs As Recordset

 Public Sub Main()
     DisplayWindow
     'Item Number is the primary field for pulling data 
     ScanTable ItemMaintenance.ItemNumber
     Cleanup
End Sub

 Private Sub DisplayWindow()
    'show vendor information screen
    frmItemProfile.txtItemNumber = ItemMaintenance.ItemNumber

'build combobox with values
    Build_Class_Group_ComboBox
    'Show the form
    frmItemProfile.Show
 End Sub
```

When I run these two methods in vba, the information displays on the form and works 100%
Now I have to code the button on the original form so this is what I have ; Test = name of the button

```
  Private Sub Test_Changed()
     frmItemProfile.Show
  End Sub
```

How can I code the button to run the program properly? If anyone could shed some light on the issue I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've tried:

```
Private Sub Test_Click()
    Main()
End Sub
```

Comment: My problem isnt the window coming up, the window appears when the button is clicked; but the issue is the fields are not being filled with the default data.

Comment: Ok, so call your `Main` method in the button click handler. Answer updated.